# How to programmatically extract an attachment from a password protected PDF?

Tags: perl, pdf, attachment

I've a password protected PDF document, inside which is attached, a CSV file. How can I programmatically extract the CSV? I tried calling [pdftk](https://www.pdflabs.com/docs/pdftk-man-page/) to unpack the attachment but that doesn't seem to work when the PDF is password protected.

```
    SHELL$ ls
    PDFattCSV.pdf
    SHELL$ pdftk PDFattCSV.pdf unpack_files
    SHELL$ ls
    CSV.csv PDFattCSV.pdf
```

Is there any Perl API to do this?

Answer (score 0):

you could decrypt the PDF file first (one of these):

```
pdftk PDFattCSV.pdf output PDFattCSV_unprotected.pdf user_pw YOURPASSWORD-HERE

pdftk PDFattCSV.pdf output PDFattCSV_unprotected.pdf user_pw YOURPASSWORD-HERE owner_pw YOURPASSWORD-HERE

pdftk PDFattCSV.pdf output PDFattCSV_unprotected.pdf input_pw YOURPASSWORD-HERE
```

Comment: `$ pdftk PDFattCSV.pdf input_pw ******** output PDFattCSV_unprotected.pdf
Error: Failed to open PDF file:
   PDFattCSV.pdf
   OWNER PASSWORD REQUIRED, but not given (or incorrect)
Errors encountered.  No output created.
Done.  Input errors, so no output created.`

Like I mentioned doesn't work with password protected PDF.
I'm able to open the PDF in Adobe Reader using this password so definitely not incorrect password.

Comment: Still the same error. Also tried owner_pw instead of user_pw and using PROMPT option. Neither seem to work.

Comment: Tried your edit and all other permutations. Still the same error.

Answer (score 0):

pdfdetach utility from xpdf worked for me:

```
    SHELL> ls
    PDFattCSV.pdf
    SHELL> pdfdetach -save 1 -upw *** PDFattCSV.pdf
    SHELL> ls
    CSV.csv PDFattCSV.csv
```